# Проверка URL

Tags: php

В старых сайтах на основе apache 2.0 сайт `http://test.net/razdel.php?id=1(')` добавляете, выдает ошибку - дыра в скрипте... А как теперь проверить, когда идёт такая строка (`http://test.net/razdel/1/`)?

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного путаете старые сайты и адресацию. В первом примере контроллер обрабатывает GET запросы и на основании полученного выводит результат. Во втором варианте используется ЧПУ, что прекрасно реализуется и на apache 2.0, ссылка, как правило, проходит переадресацию через .htaccess, после чего отдается контроллеру на обработку. А далее всё зависит от разработчика сайта, встречаются экземпляры, которым укажешь вместо `http://test.net/razdel/1/` `http://test.net/razdel/2/` и сайт посыпется, и в противоположность, есть такие, которым добавите в GET запрос любые символы, он продолжит прекрасненько работать дальше.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку =)